# Store Pricing Combinations and Sums w/ SQL

Tags: sql, sum, unique, combinations, permutation

I have a table that looks something like

```
grain 10
rice  10
bread 10
wine  20
chair 20
bed   30
desk  30
```

and I would like to create all possible combinations with the sum of the prices, including the unique values to create something like

```
grain grain grain grain 40
grain grain grain rice  40
grain grain rice  rice  40
grain grain grain desk  60
```

what would be the quick and dirtiest way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three `joins`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1, t4.col1, 
       (t1.price + t2.price + t3.price + t4.price)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.col1 <= t2.col1 join
     t t3
     on t2.col1 <= t3.col1 join
     t t4
     on t3.col1 <= t4.col1;
```

Comment: This worked but  I needed to add a SUM to the prices and group by the other columns, thanks!